# Open ports 8000 and 3000 on EC2 AWS instance

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run Django in port 8000 and React in port 3000 on an EC2 AWS instance. I first created the inbound rules for ports 8000 and 3000:

[image]

Then, I start both Django and React on ip 0.0.0.0:

- React:

  *package.json*

  ```
  {
  ...
    "scripts": {
      "start": "HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start",
      ...
     },
  }
  ```

  `sudo npm start`
- Django:

  `sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

And I can check both ports are open and listening:

`sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

[image]

However, when I try to reach the urls http://external_ip:8000/ or http://external_ip:3000/ Nothing is working. However, I can make Django server works if I change 8000 by 80.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Maybe stupid and redundant but did you assign the security groups to the EC2 instance?

Comment: Yeah, it is assigned!

Comment: Are you using the default VPC? If not, are there any settings related to NACLs?

Comment: I'm using an elastic IP, I think that's the only setting I changed

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very used to AWS therminology! I think this's what you meant.

Comment: Have you altered anything to the outgoing security groups? Is you EC2 machine behind some sort of firewall? Can you try to not use the elastic IP and use the DNS name the machine has been given by AWS directly?

Comment: In outbound rules I have: All - All -0.0.0.0/0.
How can I know about the firewall? I didn't do anything, so I don't think so.
And I tried with the DNS but It's not working either...

Comment: i am also trying to solve this issue. regarding the firewall i tried disabling the firewall on the ec2 instance with `sudo ufw disable` but that didn't help